# Не выводят ошибки формы. как исправить?

Tags: битрикс

После замены шаблона регистрации на свой. перестали выводится ошибки валидации формы. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: <?=$FORM->ShowFormErrors()?>

Comment: @humster_spb  не работает

Comment: А Вы куда этот код добавили?

Comment: @humster_spb я этот код добавил на страницу шаблона

Comment: @humster_spb проблема возникает когда я вывожу шаблон в main.register